# SFINAE compiler troubles

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stl, containers, sfinae

The following code of mine should detect whether `T` has `begin` and `end` methods:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_container
{
    template <typename U, typename U::const_iterator (U::*)() const,
                          typename U::const_iterator (U::*)() const>
    struct sfinae {};

    template <typename U> static char test(sfinae<U, &U::begin, &U::end>*);
    template <typename U> static long test(...);

    enum { value = (1 == sizeof test<T>(0)) };
};
```

And here is some test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_container<std::vector<std::string> >::value << ' ';
    std::cout << is_container<std::list<std::string> >::value << ' ';
    std::cout << is_container<std::set<std::string> >::value << ' ';
    std::cout << is_container<std::map<std::string, std::string> >::value << '\n';
}
```

On g++ 4.5.1, the output is `1 1 1 1`. On Visual Studio 2008, however, the output is `1 1 0 0`. Did I do something wrong, or is this simply a VS 2008 bug? Can anyone test on a different compiler? Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on MinGW g++ 4.4.0 (got `1 1 1 1`). Unfortunately I have no idea why it fails on VS2008, although the code looks correct.

Comment: Same on VS2010 `1 1 0 0`. I had a hunch it might be debugging STL so I tried `/DDEBUG` and `/DNDEBUG` but didn't make any difference.

Comment: You could have a look at the [`HAS_XXX` facility](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/boost/mpl/has_xxx.hpp) provided by Boost.MPL to see how they work around limited SFINAE capacities of certain compilers.

Comment: Another data point: Comeau (uses EDG, usually a good to-the-letter-of-the-standard test) appears to return `1 1 1 1` - your program compiled fine on their online try-it-out http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout with the long line commented out.

Comment: @Rup: Can you actually *run* the program on their tryitout website?

Comment: No, but since it's a compile-time check if you comment out `static long test(...);` then it should fail to compile if any answers were 0 - so I infer they're all 1s. Is that faulty logic? I do have Comeau 4.3.3 on my home PC - I'll test the real thing later if I remember.

Comment: @Rup: Oh, I thought you were referring to the last line in main when you said "the *long* line" :-) Makes sense.

Comment: @Fred: They also support `static_assert`. You can replace output with those.

Comment: Knowing VC, I would take the code to file a bug report, hinting at como and GCC getting it right. And have you tried VC10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephan T. Lavavej has [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-9-of-n) to say:

> **Please note that it is technically forbidden to take the address of a Standard Library member function.** (They can be overloaded, making `&foo::bar` ambiguous, and they can have additional default arguments, defeating attempts to disambiguate via `static_cast`.)

So I guess I'm going to use the simpler version that only checks for the nested `const_iterator` type.

Answer (score 12):

So, here's how I go about debugging these things.

First, comment out the negative alternative so you get an error instead of just a mismatch.
Next, try to instantiate the type you're putting in the function with one of the items that do not work.

At this step, I was able to instantiate your sfinae object but it still wasn't working.  "This lets me know it IS a VS bug, so the question then is how to fix it." -- *OBS*

VS seems to have troubles with SFINAE when done the way you are. *Of course it does!*  It works better when you wrap up your sfinae object.  I did that like so:

```
template <typename U, typename it_t = typename U::const_iterator >
struct sfinae 
{
  // typedef typename U::const_iterator it_t; - fails to compile with non-cont types.  Not sfinae
  template < typename U, typename IT, IT (U::*)() const, IT (U::*)() const >
  struct type_ {};

  typedef type_<U,it_t,&U::begin,&U::end> type;
};
```

Still wasn't working, but at least I got a useful error message:

`error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree> (__thiscall std::set<_Kty>::* )(void) const'`

**This lets me know that `&U::end` is not sufficient for VS (*ANY* compiler) to be able to tell which end() I want.**  ***A static_cast fixes that***:

```
  typedef type_<U,it_t,static_cast<it_t (U::*)() const>(&U::begin),static_cast<it_t (U::*)() const>(&U::end)> type;
```

Put it all back together and run your test program on it...success with VS2010.  You might find that a static_cast is actually all you need, but I left that to you to find out.

I suppose the real question now is, which compiler is right?  My bet is on the one that was consistent: g++. *Point to the wise: **NEVER** assume what I did back then.*

Edit: Jeesh... *You are wrong!*

*Corrected version:*

```
template <typename T>
struct is_container
{
    template <typename U, typename it_t = typename U::const_iterator > 
    struct sfinae 
    {
      //typedef typename U::const_iterator it_t;
      template < typename U, typename IT, IT (U::*)() const, IT (U::*)() const >
      struct type_ {};

      typedef type_<U,it_t,static_cast<it_t (U::*)() const>(&U::begin),static_cast<it_t (U::*)() const>(&U::end)> type;
    };

    template <typename U> static char test(typename sfinae<U>::type*);
    template <typename U> static long test(...);

    enum { value = (1 == sizeof test<T>(0)) };
};



#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_container<std::vector<std::string> >::value << ' ';
    std::cout << is_container<std::list<std::string> >::value << ' ';
    std::cout << is_container<std::set<std::string> >::value << ' ';
    std::cout << is_container<std::map<std::string, std::string> >::value << ' ';
    std::cout << is_container<bool>::value << '\n';
}
```

--
*The debugging above is sensible, but the assumption about the compiler was wrong headed.  G++ should have failed for the reason I emphasized above.*

Comment: @sbi @John @Rup Sadly, this code does not work. If the type does not have `begin` or `end` methods, it does not compile.

Comment: @Fred: But your original code also checked for `begin()`/`end()`, didn't it? (And what class would have a nested `const_iterator` type, but no `begin()`/`end()` returning it?)

Comment: @sbi: SFINAE means "substitution failure is **not** an error". If `T` does not have `begin` and `end` methods, then `is_container<T>::value` should still **compile** (and yield false). And that's exactly what my code does correctly in g++.

Comment: The question was asking about problems wrt the MS compiler.  The solution I provided indeed works as requested in MSVC.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you going to all that effort? If you want to check if `U::begin()` exists, why not try it?

```
template <typename T>
struct is_container
{
    template <typename U> static char test(U* u,
       typename U::const_iterator b = ((U*)0)->begin(),
       typename U::const_iterator e = ((U*)0)->end());
    template <typename U> static long test(...);

    enum { value = (1 == sizeof test<T>(0)) };
};
```

In addition to checking for the existance of `U::begin()` and `U::end()`, this also checks whether they return something that is convertible to a `const_iterator`. It also avoids the pitfall highlighted by Stephan T. Lavavej by using a call expression that must be supported, instead of assuming a particular signature.

[edit]
Sorry, this relied on VC10's template instantiation. Better approach (puts the existance check in the argument types, which *do* participate in overloading):

```
template <typename T> struct is_container
{
    // Is.
    template <typename U>
    static char test(U* u, 
                     int (*b)[sizeof(typename U::const_iterator()==((U*)0)->begin())] = 0,
                     int (*e)[sizeof(typename U::const_iterator()==((U*)0)->end())] = 0);
    // Is not.
    template <typename U> static long test(...);

    enum { value = (1 == sizeof test<T>(0)) };
};
```

Comment: Tested on VS2005, works fine even for `is_container<std::set<std::string> >::value` (is `true`)

Comment: `typename U::const_iterator b = ((U*)0)->begin()`, when we populate the default argument, it's doesn't calls the `begin` ?, can you please explain concepts why `begin` (`((U*)0)->begin()`) doesn't get's called? , Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: A default argument is evaluated at the point where the function is called. Since `test<T>()` isn't actually called (`sizeof(expr)` doesn't evaluate the expression), default arguments aren't evaluated either. However, `sizeof(test<T>(0))` does need to do overload resolution to determine the return type.

Comment: So, when we do this `((U*)0)->begin()` , (even test<T>() isn't called) it just checks the compatibility whether non-type arg `b`'s type is same as type of expression `((U*)0)->begin()` , right? . Thanks a lot:)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Yes, and that in turn requires that `U` has a member `begin`, which answers the original question.

Answer (score 3):

With C++11, there are now better ways to detect this. Instead of relying on the signature of functions, we simply call them in an expression SFINAE context:

```
#include <type_traits> // declval

template<class T>
class is_container{
  typedef char (&two)[2];

  template<class U> // non-const
  static auto test(typename U::iterator*, int)
      -> decltype(std::declval<U>().begin(), char());

  template<class U> // const
  static auto test(typename U::const_iterator*, long)
      -> decltype(std::declval<U const>().begin(), char());

  template<class>
  static two  test(...);

public:
  static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0, 0)) == 1;
};
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/k4UkX) The `int` and `long` parameters are only to disambiguate overload resolution when the container offers both (or if `iterator` is `typedef const_iterator iterator`, like `std::set` is allowed to) - literal `0` is of type `int` and forces the first overload to be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

This probably should be a comment, but I don't have enough points

@MSalters

Even though your `is_container` works (almost) and I've used your code myself, I've discovered two problems in it.

First is that type `deque<T>::iterator` is detected as a container (in gcc-4.7). It seems that `deque<T>::iterator` has `begin`/`end` members and  `const_iterator` type defined.

2nd problem is that this code is invalid according to GCC devs. I qoute: *values of default arguments are not part of the function type and do not take part in deduction*. See [GCC bug 51989](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51989)

I am currently using [this](https://github.com/lvv/scc/blob/master/meta.h) (C++11 only) for `is_container<T>`:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_container {
    template <
        typename U,
        typename S = decltype (((U*)0)->size()),
        typename I = typename U::const_iterator
    >
    static char test(U* u);
    template <typename U> static long test(...);
    enum { value = sizeof test<T>(0) == 1 };
};
```

Comment: So is `deque` not a container?

Comment: `deque` is a container, but `deque<T>::iterator` is not.

Comment: 2nd problem is real. I overlooked 14.7.1/2; default arguments are not instantiated with the template themselves.