# C++11: Specialize/restrict method on depending on a container's value_type

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, specialization

I have a template `action` method that accepts any kind of STL container `C`. However the contained items (`C::value_type`) must be either `ClassA` or `ClassB`. So far so good:

```
struct Whatever {
    template<typename C>
    void action(const C& c) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<typename C::value_type, ClassA>::value ||
                      std::is_same<typename C::value_type, ClassB>::value,
                      "Wrong C::value_type");
        // do something with c
    }
};

// Usage:
Whatever w;
w.action(std::vector<ClassA>{1, 2, 3});
w.action(std::unordered_set<ClassB>{1, 2, 3});
```

Note: the enclosing class is *not* a template, the only template is this very `action` method.

Now, depending on `C::value_type`, I want to specialize the behaviour of the method. You guessed it, that's where my brain starts melting.

---

**I believe SFINAE is the way to go** but obviously I'm too rusty to make it work properly: after several hours, tons of helper `structs` and way too much coffee for my own health, the compiler just keeps yelling the usual 500+ template errors at me. No point in copying either my helper `structs` or the errors here, that's pretty much useless junk.

However, I have to admit I didn't really keep in touch with all the C++ template (r)evolutions (or even use SFINAE, at that) since a good decade so it's no wonder I'm failing so hard.

I strongly suspect C++11 now has easy, ready-to-use SFINAE-like tools to achieve what I want but I don't even know where to begin searching in the documentation. Search engines didn't help either, there's just too much new information at once for me to be able to understand what is/isn't relevant to my problem.

Since I'm at a total loss, I'll just take baby steps and ask SO... My question is two-fold:

- **How can I specialize the behaviour of the method depending on the actual type of `C::value_type` using modern C++11 template tools?**
- **Optionally, is there a standard way to check if `C` actually is a container?**

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering why don't you do this:

```
 template<typename C>
 void action(const C& c) 
 {
        static_assert(std::is_same<typename C::value_type, ClassA>::value ||
                      std::is_same<typename C::value_type, ClassB>::value,
                      "Wrong C::value_type");

      action_worker(c, static_cast<typename C::value_type*>(0));
 }

private:

 template<typename C>
 void action_worker(const C& c, ClassA *) 
 {
     //specialized code when C::value_type is ClassA
 }

 template<typename C>
 void action_worker(const C& c, ClassB *) 
 {
     //specialized code when C::value_type is ClassB
 }
```

Now depending on `C::value_type`, the second argument to `action_worker` can be either `ClassA*` or `ClassB*`. That will enable compiler to choose the correct overload where you write the specialized code.

For the second part of your question, see the implementation of `is_container` class template in this answer:

- [SFINAE compiler troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4348381/415784)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh my, silly me... I *should* have thought about that but I was searching in such an opposite direction that I probably never would  have. O_o Thanks a lot! This is definitely an excellent answer to the first part of my question, very straight to the point.

Comment: @syam: See the edit. It links to a solution to the second part of your question.

Comment: Thanks again, you nailed it. Wish I could upvote you again. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you only support those two types I would consider using enable_if:

```
struct Whatever
{
    template<typename C>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename C::value_type, ClassA>::value, void>::type
    action(const C& c)
    {
        std::cout << "ClassA\n";
    }

    template<typename C>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename C::value_type, ClassB>::value, void>::type
    action(const C& c)
    {
        std::cout << "ClassB\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: Indeed that is the kind of stuff I was originally after. Thanks, now I have somewhere to start the investigation of those new features... :)